# Tensorflow, error in using unique_with_counts function

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm implementing a K nearest neighbor algorithm in tensorflow, and I'm getting the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op'UniqueWithCounts' used by node UniqueWithCounts (defined at knn.py:92) with these attrs: [T=DT_BOOL, out_idx=DT_INT32]
```

The trace says that the error happens in the following line:

```
Caused by op 'UniqueWithCounts', defined at:
  File "knn.py", line 92, in <module>
    find_u_labels, find_idex, find_counts = tf.unique_with_counts(find_labels_k_closest_tr_products)
```

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
x = tf.placeholder(float, shape=X_train.shape)
y = tf.placeholder(float, shape=X_test.shape[1:])
computeL0Dist = tf.count_nonzero(x - y, axis=[1])
find_k_closest_tr_products = tf.contrib.framework.argsort(computeL0Dist, direction='ASCENDING')
find_labels_k_closest_tr_products = tf.gather(y_train, find_k_closest_tr_products[0:paramk])
print('SHAPE', find_labels_k_closest_tr_products.shape)
find_u_labels, find_idex, find_counts = tf.unique_with_counts(find_labels_k_closest_tr_products)
find_predicted_label = tf.gather(find_u_labels, tf.argmax(find_counts))
```

Comment: which version of tensorflow are you using?

Comment: Tensorflow version: 1.13.1

Comment: I think that only has defined kernels for CPU (see [`unique_op.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.13.1/tensorflow/core/kernels/unique_op.cc)). Are you using a `with tf.device('/gpu:*'):` context?

Comment: My machine doesn't have a GPU

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the original error message it tells you that you are passing a tensor of type `tf.bool` to the `tf.unique_with_counts()` operation:

> by node UniqueWithCounts (defined at knn.py:92) with these attrs: [**T=DT_BOOL**, out_idx=DT_INT32]

This operation does not support bools. Looking at your code, I suspect this wasn't what you were intending?